# Manter caracteres na substituição com regex no gedit

Tags: regex, csv

Tenho o seguinte segmento de texto num arquivo .csv

```
5/29/17;08:17;Fulano;Teatro Companhia
Rua do Canto, 301/305
Esquina da rua meio
De segunda a sexta das 9h as 18h
5/29/17;08:18;Ciclano;legal
```

Preciso que as linhas 2,3 e 4 fiquem junto com a linha 1 separadas por "|" e para isso utilizei a seguinte expressão regular para localizar as quebras de linha que não comecem com um número

```
\n[^[0-9]
```

porém quando peço para substituir ele apaga a primeira letra de cada linha e o arquivo fica assim:

```
5/29/17;08:17;Fulano;Teatro Companhia|ua do Canto, 301/305|squina da rua meio|e segunda a sexta das 9h as 18h
5/29/17;08:18;Ciclano;legal
```

Gostaria de saber como posso usar uma expressão que localize as ocorrencias desejadas sem apagar os caracteres que iniciam a linha seguinte.

estou usando o programa Gedit para fazer este processo, com o comando localizar e substituir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa de usar um [lookahead positivo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
\n(?=[^0-9])
```

Este operador faz com a expressão regular veja se o caracter seguinte combina com a expressão dada. Neste caso, verifica que o caracter a seguir a nova linha `\n` não e um número.

Pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vNsZm5) (em C#).